# Cannot get aurelia-interactjs plugin to work using Aurelia CLI

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying out the [aurelia-interactjs plugin](https://github.com/eriklieben/aurelia-interactjs) to see if it meets my needs. I installed it into a new aurelia cli project by following all of the installation steps. I then added code for the Dragging section of the [interactjs demo](http://interactjs.io). The browser console displays the following error stating that interact is not a function:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: interact is not a function. (In 'interact(this.element)', 'interact' is undefined)
    attached@http://localhost:9005/node_modules/aurelia-interactjs/dist/amd/interact-draggable.js:18:21
```

Here's my code:

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <div id="drag-1" interact-draggable.bind="interactjsOptions">
    <p> You can drag one element </p>
  </div>
  <div id="drag-2" interact-draggable.bind="interactjsOptions">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.interactjsOptions = {
            // enable inertial throwing
            inertia: true,
            // keep the element within the area of it's parent
            restrict: {
                restriction: "parent",
                endOnly: true,
                elementRect: {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 1,
                    right: 1
                }
            },
            // enable autoScroll
            autoScroll: true,

            // call this function on every dragmove event
            onmove: dragMoveListener,
            // call this function on every dragend event
            onend: function(event) {
                var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

                textEl && (textEl.textContent =
                    'moved a distance of ' +
                    (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                        event.dy * event.dy) | 0) + 'px');
            }
        };
    }
}


function dragMoveListener(event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
        target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
}
```

Comment: It's a bug, there seems to be an inconsistency between the typescript definition and the actual code. The definition specifies the import as "interact.js" while in code it actually is "interact". JSPM handles this with the mapping it creates I think. In the require/CLI case this mapping between "interact.js" and "interact" isn't created. Will look into it and update the package.

Comment: @Erik Looking into this further, I discovered that I was using nodejs 5.5. Not sure how that happened since I specifically remember installing v4.x. Anyway, I upgraded to the latest node v6 and the error is now gone. However, when I try to drag, nothing happens (and the dragMoveListener function is never called).

Comment: @Erik Do you see anything in my code (I'm totally new to interactjs) that could cause drag not to work or do you still think there is a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry, wrote the above in the bus on my commute to work on my phone didn't read all the code :-)

If you want to have the basic draggable sample (first one from http://interactjs.io/), which allows you to just drag elements around:

app.css

```
.draggable {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 10%;

  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;

  border-radius: 0.75em;
  padding: 4%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="app.css"></require>
  <div
    interact-draggable.bind="interactOptions" 
    interact-dragend.delegate="dragEnd($event)" 
    interact-dragmove.delegate="dragMoveListener($event)" 
    class="draggable">
    <p> You can drag one element </p>
  </div>
  <div 
    interact-draggable.bind="interactOptions" 
    interact-dragend.delegate="dragEnd($event)" 
    interact-dragmove.delegate="dragMoveListener($event)" 
    class="draggable">
      <p> with each pointer </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

app.ts (if you remove the public keyword in the function it will be valid js I think)

```
export class App {
  public dragMoveListener(event) {
      var target = event.target,
          // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
          x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.detail.dx,
          y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.detail.dy;

      // translate the element
      target.style.webkitTransform =
          target.style.transform =
          'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

      // update the posiion attributes
      target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
      target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  public dragEnd(event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.detail.dx * event.detail.dx +
                     event.detail.dy * event.detail.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }

  public interactOptions = {
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,
  };
}
```